# Error while trying to delete a personalized domain on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns

I have some DNS records configured on my project, and now im tryng to delete some of them, but i received an error about dont have permission to remove my domains. What im make wrong?

[Error print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkNfW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uhmmm this error sometimes is related to the lack of permissions over this mapped domain on App engine, I'd suggest you to verify the ownership of this domain by changing the settings on the URL described below and then open it in your browser

> https://console.cloud/.google.com/logs/viewer?project=[YOUR-PROJECT-ID-HERE]&interval=NO_LIMIT&resource=gae_app&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D"gae_app"%0AprotoPayload.methodName%3D"google.appengine.v1beta.DomainMappings.CreateDomainMapping"

Once you confirm the ownership of this domain, you could proceed to run the gcloud command for this matter with the account identified as domain's owner

(I know it could be a little bit tedious using the gcloud command but it could give us a better description of this error)

> gcloud app domain-mappings delete "DOMAIN" verbosity=debug

the last flag will let you know what is going on with the operation, so if there's still an error you can share the outcome of this error here or directly with the Google Cloud Platform Support Team.

[Here's a link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/domain-mappings/delete) to the command's doc if you want to learn more about its usage

Comment: The tip about the CLI solved my problem, when i try to delete throught CLI it return a error with much more information.